# Traversing through child nodes of xml using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I am very new to this concept and struggling to achieve the below requirement.

I have the below xml object in my javascript variable named "detailJSTotal".

```
<response>
<div>
    <p>
        <label>
            ID:
        </label>
        812161
    </p>
    <p>
        <label>
            Name:
        </label>
        252
    </p>
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="text4.xml">
        more...
    </a>
</div>
<div>
    <p>
        <label>
            ID:
        </label>
        812162
    </p>
    <p>
        <label>
            Name:
        </label>
        252
    </p>
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="test2.xml">
        more...
    </a>
</div>
<div>
    <p>
        <label>
            ID:
        </label>
        812163
    </p>
    <p>
        <label>
            Name:
        </label>
        252
    </p>
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="text.xml">
        more...
    </a>
</div>
<div>
    <p>
        <label>
            ID:
        </label>
        812164
    </p>
    <p>
        <label>
            Name:
        </label>
        252
    </p>
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="test1.xml">
        more...
    </a>
</div>
```

Here root element (response) contains multiple < div > elements. Each < div > element contains < label > element and it's value and < a > element.

My requirement is to get the value of < a > element's "onclick" attribute for a given < label > 'ID' value of a < div > element.

Example:

I may want to get the value of "onclick" attribute of < a > element by providing the ID < label > value as '812161'. The return value should be "text4.xml" in the example above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try Jquery's  `xmlParser`; like this

```js
var detailJSTotal= `<response>
<div>
    <p>
        <label>
            ID:
        </label>
        812161
    </p>
    <p>
        <label>
            Name:
        </label>
        252
    </p>
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="text4.xml">
        more...
    </a>
</div>
<div>
    <p>
        <label>
            ID:
        </label>
        812162
    </p>
    <p>
        <label>
            Name:
        </label>
        252
    </p>
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="test2.xml">
        more...
    </a>
</div>
<div>
    <p>
        <label>
            ID:
        </label>
        812163
    </p>
    <p>
        <label>
            Name:
        </label>
        252
    </p>
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="text.xml">
        more...
    </a>
</div>
<div>
    <p>
        <label>
            ID:
        </label>
        812164
    </p>
    <p>
        <label>
            Name:
        </label>
        252
    </p>
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="test1.xml">
        more...
    </a>
</div></response>`;
  xmlDOM = $( $.parseXML( detailJSTotal) );
function getAttrForID(id){
  console.log($($(xmlDOM).find("p:contains(" + id + ")").siblings("a")[0]).attr("onclick"));
  return $($(xmlDOM).find("p:contains(" + id + ")").siblings("a")[0]).attr("onclick");
}

console.log(getAttrForID("812161"));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Hi can we something like below. It is restricted using looping in my case.

Comment: Then what is the return type you required?

Comment: You need just the first ID of entire response?

Comment: @santoshM Got you :), Now use this `getAttrForID` function get Attr  for given ID

Comment: Let me know your actual requirement? You need a traversal without looping?

Comment: Yes, as I give the ID label  value, I should get it's sibling < a > element onclick attribute's value.

Comment: Below response, suites my requirement. With the change some thing like this should work: ('label:contains("ID")'.text()== myId ).attr("onclick").

Comment: Okay, Let me try once more :)

Comment: Thanks :). I am really sorry that, my mind is totally blank to work around with the below solution.

Comment: FYI, I could work with your solution and it's working fine. But looping is what I am worried of. So, tried the above solution given by Dario and there are the things missing in it which makes it fail to work as expected.

Comment: Now check the solution, I think it's meet your requirement.

Comment: Excellent.. Working.. Thanks for your time and help.. :)

Answer (score 1):

Just load your xml via jQuery:

```
var $xml = $(detailJSTotal);
```

You can now use jQuery all jQuery-functions and select all information you need.
For example use `find()`:

```
var $label = $xml.find('label:contains("test")');
return $label.next('a').attr('onclick');
```

Note: Untested and just written out of my head.

Comment: Thanks Dario.. You have given confidence to my hope that it can be done this way. Below answer exactly suits and works for my requirement.